# Instagrm Rate limit issue

Tags: api, instagram, rate-limiting

I am developing a mobile application that will request Instagram server for searching photos with the hashtags.Client id is passed with the request.

Since the request limit provided by Instagram is 5000/hour so my question is:-

While requesting api of Instagram via client id rate limit is considered in respect of client id or IP address?

Please suggest me on the same.

I have read the doc but it was not mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Instagram Developer site (endpoints)](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/):

> Limits Be nice. If you're sending too many requests too quickly, we'll
>   send back a 503 error code (server unavailable).
>
> You are limited to 5000 requests per hour **per access_token or
>   client_id overall**. Practically, this means you should (when possible)
>   authenticate users so that limits are well outside the reach of a
>   given user.

see also ["Rate Limit Exceeded Instagram Error"](http://imranakbar.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/rate-limit-exceeded-instagram-error/):

> I tried to count my likes until i hit “Rate Limit Exceeded” Error, It
>   came around 100 – 150 Photos, and i waited for 5 mins and tried to
>   like again then the error goes off until i reach some 50 to 60 pics,
>   from the analysis i suppose Instagram is permitting to like 100 – 200
>   photos Per Hour.. and for Follows its 60 – 100…